# Google map api check marker is within the bound

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to check whether markers are within the bound and trigger an onclick event. But no luck on checking if markers are within the bound tried using getPosition() and contain().

can someone point out how to check whether markers are in the bound?

```
 function _onMapZoom () {
            console.log('testing')
            if(map.zoom < mcOptions.maxZoom){
                return;
            }

            var mapMarkers = oms.markersNearAnyOtherMarker();
            if (mapMarkers.length <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            var ne = bounds.getNorthEast(); // LatLng of the north-east corner
            var sw = bounds.getSouthWest(); // LatLng of the south-west corner
            var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng());
            var se = new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng());

            for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
                var element = mapMarkers[i];

                //CHECK IF LAT LON OF MARKER IS WITHIN BOUNDS
                var markerIsOrNotInBounds = map.getBounds().contains(mapMarkers.getPosition());
                console.log(markerIsOrNotInBounds)

                if (markerIsOrNotInBounds) {
                    continue;
                }

                gm.event.trigger(marker[i], 'click');
            }
        }
```

Comment: `var markerIsOrNotInBounds = map.getBounds().contains(element.getPosition());`

Comment: yeah managed to fix that before the answer, now I want to trigger spiderfier map clusterer if markers are in bound. Tried Click event but that only opens the infoWindow and not spread the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may only be 1 group of spiderfied markers, furthermore clicking on a spiderfied marker will unspiderfy the current group of spiderfied markers.

Solution: Immediately leave the function when a click has been triggered.

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',function() {
      var gm  = google.maps,
          map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                  center: new gm.LatLng(50, 0), 
                  zoom: 6
                }),
          oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map,
                {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true}),
          places=[{lat:50,lng:0},{lat:51,lng:-1},{lat:50,lng:1}];

      //some random markers
      for(var p=0;p<places.length;++p){
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          (function(index){
          var marker=new gm.Marker({map:map,
                                    position:{lat:(Math.random()*.1)+places[p].lat,
                                              lng:(Math.random()*.1)+places[p].lng}});
          oms.addMarker(marker);
          })(i)
        }
      }
      
      
      function _onMapZoom () {
        var bounds  = map.getBounds(),
            markers = oms.markersNearAnyOtherMarker();
        for(var i=0;i<markers.length;++i){
          if(//when marker is within map-bounds 
              bounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition())
             ){
            gm.event.trigger(markers[i],'click',{latLng:markers[i].getPosition()});
            //no need to trigger further clicks
            return;
          }
        }
      }
      
      //wait until map-projection is available  until you set the listener
      
      gm.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle',function(){
        gm.event.addListener(this,'zoom_changed',_onMapZoom)
        gm.event.trigger(this,'zoom_changed');
      });
      
    });
```

```css
html,body,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&amp;sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, managed to work things out but I was looking for this one gm.event.addListener(this,'zoom_changed',_onMapZoom)
        gm.event.trigger(this,'zoom_changed'); but instead I used timeout so it kind override the idle state then trigger the onMapZoon func. I will mark your answer :)